# V8 Engine Embedded

Tags: javascript, jquery, c++, node.js, embedded-v8

I was following a tutorial online about NodeJS and they stated that NodeJS is a C++ program which embeds the V8 JS engine in it to provide extra features for JS. So whenever the V8 engine sees a particular keyword that is not in the ECAMScript standard, it will invoke the written C++ code for that particular keyword.

My question is for jQuery does it utilize this method as well? Since jQuery is written in pure Javascript so does it only utilize the ECMAScript standards of JS to provide DOM manipulation, AJAX, JSON parsing, etc.? Or is it that DOM manipulation and those extra features is not in the standard in JS, but those features are made available through Google Chrome which is a C++ program or your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding of how node.js works is a bit off, but no matter because jQuery is 100% Javascript.  It's just a library written in Javascript.  It does what it does entirely through Javascript.  There is no native code in jQuery.

Everything that jQuery does is built on top of existing Javascript functions that already exist in the browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So NodeJS is just a runtime environment for running Javascript that allows you to deal with Databases, deal with files, etc. using Javascript?

Comment: @LP45 - It's a runtime environment for Javascript with built in access to things interesting to servers like networking, the file system, launching processes, system info, etc... that supports an add-in framework so new modules can be added into the system (such as databases).